# implement zoom in and out in richtextbox for touchscreen

Tags: c#, wpf

implement zoom in and out in Wpf rich textbox for touchscreen when the user touch the screen and try to zoom it in or out how to do this programatically because i created the rich textbox in the runtime

Comment: Please read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a better question. Also, try using some punctuation... it *really* helps us to understand. For your answer, please take a good look at the [`Viewbox` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might not fully solve your problem, but it should give you some startup-

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">  
     <Slider x:Name="Scale" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Minimum="1" Maximum="20"/>
     <RichTextBox>
      <RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=Scale, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=Scale, Path=Value}"/>
      </RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
     </RichTextBox>
  </DockPanel>
```

Comment: I need this implementation in c# because i create the rich-box in runtime